# Environment.Version equivalent in core clr

Tags: c#, coreclr, dnx50

The following code is valid for the `dnx451` framework but not the `dnxcore50`

```
string ver = Environment.Version
```

This method does not exist:

[image]

Is there an equivalent property in the dnxcore50 framework?

### Update

as per Victors answer you can use `PlatformServices.Default.Runtime` eg:

```
Console.WriteLine("env: {0} {1}", PlatformServices.Default.Runtime.RuntimeType, PlatformServices.Default.Runtime.RuntimeVersion);
```

output: (on dnx451)

> env: Clr 1.0.0-rc1-16231

output: (on dnxcore50)

> env: CoreClr 1.0.0-rc1-16231

Comment: It corresponds [the documentation](http://dotnet.github.io/api/System.Environment.html#properties). It seems that `Version` property is dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the properties in [IRuntimeEnvironment](https://github.com/aspnet/PlatformAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions/IRuntimeEnvironment.cs) to get information about the runtime. The following properties are available:

- RuntimeType
- RuntimeArchitecture
- RuntimeVersion
- RuntimePath

Comment: ...and use `new DefaultRuntimeEnvironment().RuntimeVersion` ??

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.dll` doesnt contain `DefaultRuntimeEnvironment` (in rc1) - can you please elaborate on how this works ?

Comment: Use `PlatformServices.Default.Runtime`. Here's an example: https://github.com/aspnet/Testing/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Testing/TestPlatformHelper.cs#L11

Comment: Here is what I used with dotnet core 1.1: `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application.RuntimeFramework.Version` after including nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions