# How to get info about the current runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-core

In a C# program, I need to get information about the runtime environment in which the program is running.

Essentially, I need to know if the current program is running in .NET Core or in Full .NET Framework 4.x.

Something like the following might work:

```
public string GetRuntimeVersion()
{
 #if NET451
    return "net451";
 #elseif netcoreapp11
    return "netcoreapp11"; 
 #elseif netstandard14
    return "netcoreapp14";
 #endif
...
}
```

**But is there a better way?**

Comment: #if is a compiler directive - you would only ever be able to compile with one of those options - so not be getting the runtime info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions/) !

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;

var runtimeInfo = PlatformServices.Default.Application.RuntimeFramework;
```

The `PlatformServices.Default.Application.RuntimeFramework` property contains info such as the identifier of the runtime and its version. And is available on .net core.

Credit goes to:

- [Victor Hurdugaci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149064/victor-hurdugaci) for [his comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35157810/1182189)
- [Jurjen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7397065/jurjen) for pointing out `System.Environment.Version` which somehow led me to [Victor Hurdugaci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149064/victor-hurdugaci)'s comment

Comment: The Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions package is now deprecated, with no replacement.  (Some of the functionality is built in to .NET 5+, but that doesn't help if you're still targeting .NET Standard 2.x or older .NET Core.)

Answer (score 2):

Apperently there's also `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` now.

> PROPERTIES
> FrameworkDescription
> Gets the name of the .NET installation on which an app is running.

> OSArchitecture
> Gets the platform architecture on which the current app is running.

> OSDescription
> Gets a string that describes the operating system on which the app is running.

> ProcessArchitecture
> Gets the process architecture of the currently running app.

> RuntimeIdentifier
> Gets the platform on which an app is running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation?view=net-6.0

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);
        Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture);
        Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.OSDescription);
        Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture);
        Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.RuntimeIdentifier);
    }
}
```

```
.NET 6.0.0-rtm.21522.10
X64
Linux 5.4.0-1064-azure #67~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 11:38:21 UTC 2021
X64
debian.11-x64
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/sZ3OKj

Funnily enough this doesn't seem to work in powershell, at least not for me when trying to run: `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::RuntimeIdentifier`

Answer (score 0):

Check the `System.Environment.Version` property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx).

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", Environment.Version.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, System.Environment.Version is not available in .net core

Comment: Well, that's how you know of course :)  There is no point in checking it later.